# How to check if cronjob expression is due

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I have a cron expression like `0 04 14 ? * FRI *` and I have a `Date`. I want to check if that date matches this cronjob expression. In other words, I would like to know if a cronjob will be executed at the given date.

I have found [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) but I haven't found a Utility class for simply checking if a cronjob expression matches a .

Does anybody knows if there is library I can use for that?

Comment: This comment won't add much but just to let you know I actually was looking for that feature a while back and gave up...

Comment: Thanks for letting me know

Comment: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/CronExpression.html#isSatisfiedBy(java.util.Date) is not you are looking for?

Comment: @Mateusz this could be it